# Typescript inheritance where datatypes in IntelliSense is any instead of expected number

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, ntvs

I have a tiny code implementation in Typescript where I have a class either implementing an interface or extending a class.

```
interface ITest {
    run(id: number): void
}

abstract class Test implements ITest {

    abstract run(id);
}

class TestExtension extends Test
{
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public run(id) { }
}

class TestImplementation implements ITest {
    constructor() {

    }

    public run(id) { }
}
```

Both shows wrong Intellisense where I expected id to by of type 'number':

```
(method) TestExtension.run(id: any): void
(method) TestImplementation.run(id: any): void
```

I can of course set method implementation to be `public(id: number) { }` but I don't see why I have to do this.

Can someone enlighten me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of `implements ITest` is a bit in correct. TypeScript interface implementation is not like other langauges, it is purely a compile time contract static that members of the class must be compatible with the interface definition.

So like the following is correct:

```
let foo: number;
let bar; // inferred any 
foo = bar;
```

the following is also correct

```
interface IFoo {
  foo: number
}
class Foo implements IFoo {
  foo; // Inferred any
}
```

The function argument is also any in your code without an explicit signature

## Fix

Be explicit: `public run(id) { }` to `public run(id: number) { }` And optionally compile with `noImplicitAny` if you want the compiler to catch these cases for you

Comment: I see, but don't you think it's kinda strange that my abstract class and abstract method that doesn't have any implementation is still any in the extending class?

I have to think a little different about Typescript then